# On line bundle on curves lying on a surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth irreducible curve on a complex algebraic surface $X$ and $L$ be a base point free line bundle on $C$ such that we have $H^0(L) \otimes H^0(\mathcal O_X(m)) \hookrightarrow H^0(L(m))$ for some positive $m$.  Also assume that $H^0(L), H^0(\mathcal O_X(m)) \neq 0$ and $\text{deg}(L(m)) >0$.

Then my question is :  Under what condition(s)(cohomological or otherwise) on the line bundle $L$ the above inclusion becomes an isomorphism?

An obvious answer is to assume $H^0(L(m)) =0$, But I am looking for condition(s) other than this.

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your question, $X$ does not really play any role. I am not sure what kind of answer you are looking for.

One has an exact sequence, $0\to E\to H^0(L)\otimes O_C\to L\to 0$, since $L$ is base point free. Tensoring with $O_C(m)$ and taking global sections, one has $0\to H^0(E(m))\to H^0(L)\otimes H^0(O_C(m))\to H^0(L(m))\to H^1(E(m))\to H^0(L)\otimes H^1(O_C(m))$. Your assumption says $H^0(E(m))=0$. So, the required surjectivity is equivalent to $H^1(E(m))\to H^0(L)\otimes H^1(O_C(m))$ being injective.

Comment: Is the isomorphism $H^0(X, \mathcal O_X(m)) \cong H^0(C, \mathcal O_C(m))$ the reason behind the statement "$X$ does not play any role"? Are there concrete examples when this happens? Actually I'm looking for    this kind of situations occuring in smooth curves lying  on  general surface of degree $d \geq 5$ in $\mathbb P^3$.

Comment: Yes, in that sense $X$ does play a role, since the natural map $H^0(O_X(m))\to H^0(O_C(m))$ may not be an isomorphism. I presume you know that for a very general such surface, this map is onto by Noether-Lefschetz.

Comment: Does there exist a classification of such curves which admits such base point free line bundles such that $H^1(E(m)) \to H^0(L) \otimes H^1(\mathcal O_C(m)$ is injective?

Comment: There are too many variables-$d, C, L, m$. Do you want to ask a narrower more focussed question?

Comment: yes I will separately post a more specific question.